# Jquery hover not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
    <style>
      .navigation ul li {
          float: left;
          list-style: none;
          padding: 10px;
          margin-top: 10px;
      }
          .navigation ul li a {
             display: block;
             text-decoration: none;
             font-weight: bold;
          }         
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".navigation ul li a").hover(function(){
          $(this).animate({ color: 'blue'}, "slow");
       }, function() {
          $(this).animate({ color: 'red'}, "slow");
       });
         });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
       <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fruits &amp; Veg</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Food Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Locate store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fan Club</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to hover in the animate a color change, but it does not work. 
Similarly, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suxedung/ANUT3/797/), it works. I do not know why? please help me

Comment: Post this to a jsfiddle please.

Comment: Pointy answer is what you're looking for. But.. Please, insert meta tag charset and other basic stuff too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing jQuery but you're *not* importing jQuery UI. You do so in the fiddle but not in the code you posted here.

Animating colors requires jQueryUI.

Comment: hey! I have inserted into the jQueryUI library by adding this line to the head tag, but still not be.
    <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Make sure that the library is loaded - the browser's network console will tell you that. (You should probably load a newer version of jQuery UI too.)

Comment: How to make sure the library has been loaded jquery? 
Sr, I'm newbie

Comment: When you load your page, the browser's "Network" tab will show you all the HTTP transactions and their status. You should also be checking the developer console for error messages.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in pure CSS:

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPghq/2/)**

```
.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition:color 1s;
  -webkit-transition:color 1s;
  -moz-transition:color 1s;
  color:#f00;
}    

.navigation ul li a:hover{
    color:#00f;
}
```

As to WHY it wont work, is because animating colours requires jQueryUI (See [Pointy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23760773/2471423))

Comment: Thank u ! but I want use Jquery. Beacause I need to display on IE 7

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use css3 transition example you can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<style>
  .navigation ul li {
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
  }
      .navigation ul li a {
         display: block;
         text-decoration: none;
         color:blue;
         font-weight: bold; transition:1s;
      } 
    .navigation ul li a:hover {color:red;} 

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fruits &amp; Veg</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Food Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locate store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fan Club</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u, but css3 Transition not support IE9 and early